# JSP/Java/Tomcat | <jsp:inlude> Class not Found

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I created a Tomcat Server on witch I run my web-application.

In my source code I have this line:

```
<jsp:include page="jspinclude/form.jsp"/>
```

When I start the server it gives me the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.jspinclude.form_jsp
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
```

Why does this hapen?

My Project Structure looks perfectly fine.

How do I get this jsp file compilled?/Does it even get installed on the server?

If more information is needed just comment! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your jsp namespace is having some sort of conflict.

Try including your jsp file using `<%@ include file="jspinclude/form.jsp" %>`

Answer (score 0):

You must type:

```
<%@ include file="filename" %>
```

Read offical reference document: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnajb.html